# Is there a way to explore directly an array in an array without passing by the first?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I'm using preg_match_all() to get matches of the parameters of my url. Problem is matches function send me back an array of array. So it became difficult to explore it with a foreach function (to replace parameters by default parameters for example).

Is there a way to explore straight an array of array and send back the value of the second array, not the first, without passing by the first ?

I put you a simple example of my problem:

```
$var = "abababa";

preg_match_all("#(a)#", $var, $matches);

$args = array_slice ($matches, 1);

var_dump($args)
```

arg return me :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'a' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
      3 => string 'a' (length=1)
```

And I wish it could return just

```
   array (size=5)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'a' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
      3 => string 'a' (length=1)
```

Therefore to be able to replace args elements by othes (default elements for example).

Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: In PHP 7 you can do simply `$args = array_slice ($matches,1)[0];`

Comment: Thank you :) I'm still novice at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Anacarde no problem, it's just good to get questions closed and off the "unanswered" list. As a bonus, you get +2 rep! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$var = "abababa";

preg_match_all("#(a)#", $var, $matches);

$args = array_slice ($matches[0], 1); // notice we are accessing the first element of $matches

var_dump($args);
```

This should produce your desired output.